# Tableau - Questions on map

Tags: tableau-api

I am stuck with creating a map in tableau and was wondering if I could get some guidance here.

Parameters that I have: 
1) Week/Month/Year which is connected to the following dimension "Week/Month/Year"

```
Case [Parameters].[Week/Month/Year]
when 'Year' then [Event Date -  Year]
when 'Week' then [Event Date-Week]
when 'Month' then [Event Date -  Month]
END
```

2) KPI which is connected to the following calculated field "KPi_new"

```
Case [Parameters].[KPI]
when 'SS%' then -[SS% ]
when 'CR%' then -[SC%]
when 'AR%' then -[AR%]
when 'Clicks' then SUM([Clicks])
when 'Signup Starts' then SUM([Starts_old])
when 'Signup Completes' then SUM([Sign Ups])
when 'Activs' then SUM([Actives till date])
END
```

3) I also have a country & sub region filter

I am trying to create a map where it shows me KPI per country for the time frame chosen in the parameter "Week/month/year"

To explain it better: If i choose, week in the "week/month/year" parameter and SS% in the "KPI" parameter then the map should give me, average SS% in all the weeks till date for that country/subregion

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is create a calculated field that brings together your two  choices and calculates the result. This is the field you will drag onto your view to display.

As your view has the potential to show the data at multiple levels (week/month/year) you will want to leverage a **level of detail** calculation. To do this create the following calculated field:

```
{ FIXED [Week/Month/Year]: avg([KPi_New])}
```

Without a full understanding of how the input fields into your KPI_New field is set up and how the weeks, months and days are formatted in your data this may not work out of the box. 
So you can add a screenshot of some example data to further refine this answer.